# flutterfire configure FirebaseCommandException

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am following https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios to add Firebase to my existing Flutter app. However, when running `flutterfire configure`, I encountered the following problem:

```
FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase apps:create android my_app (android) --package-name=com.example.my_app --json --project=myapp-firebase 
ERROR: Failed to create Android app for project myapp-firebase. See firebase-debug.log for more info.
```

Answer (score 1):

After a painstakingly long search for a solution, I realized that it is because the app name should not contain underscores. Changing my_app to myapp solved the issue.